SSH protocol RFC clarification
Good day. Was hoping one could help me understand what this means in the SSH RFC:
 Arbitrary-length padding, such that the total length of
         (packet_length || padding_length || payload || random padding)
(packet_length || padding_length || payload || random padding) 

Total length of what? The bytes holding those value or the values themselves.

I'm assuming that you are quoting section 6 of RFC 4253, specifically the random padding section, which reads:

random padding

    Arbitrary-length padding, such that the total length of
    (packet_length || padding_length || payload || random padding)
    is a multiple of the cipher block size or 8, whichever is
    larger.  There MUST be at least four bytes of padding.  The
    padding SHOULD consist of random bytes.  The maximum amount of
    padding is 255 bytes.



here the term "total length" means the number of bytes used to represent the concatenated values. The packet length is a uint32 and so uses 4 bytes, the padding length is a single byte. Thus if we had (for example) 17 bytes of payload (giving 22 concatenated bytes without padding) and a cipher with block size 8 bytes, we could add 10, 18, 26,..., or 252 bytes of padding to make the "total length" 32, 40, ..., or 274 bytes (each of which is a multiple of 8 bytes and has at least 4 bytes of padding and at most 255).

Thank you for the perfect sense answer
